# How to save object into variable mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, variables

I want to save a single Object to a variable

```
var query= user.findOne({ip:'127.0.0.1'});
  var test= query.exec(function (err, user) {
  if (err) return handleError(err);
  return user.ip;

  console.log('%s ', user.ip) 
})
    console.log(test);
```

The console.log is showing the right value while my test variable is showing something like {domain:null, _events....

Comment: `exec` returns a query object, not the result.  The result is only available in the callback as the `user` parameter.

Comment: I want to check if an user entry with that ip is existing and save true of false into a variable wether it is existing or not. I don't got it to work,so i tryed to save the whole ip. Is there any way of doing this.